# What does the end of this paragraph mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Tensions remain high with arch-rival India after the nuclear-armed
>   neighbors launched tit-for-tat airstrikes in February following a
>   suicide bombing in Indian Kashmir which was claimed by Pakistan-based
>   militants.

What did the Pakistan militants claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pakistan militants "claimed" **responsibility** for the suicide bombing.

The writer of the article uses this construction because it avoids saying that the militants actually carried out the attack. The sentence means that the Pakistan militants approve of the attack, and that they *say* they were the ones who did it (which may not even be true).